# A way to "Merge" dataframes, with Matching values but Complex Interactions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two different DataFrames that I want to merge with EventNames and Class Code columns. I saw some threads that are there, but I could not find the solution for my issue. I also read this document and tried different combinations, however, did not work well.
I have one massive pandas dataframe with this structure:

df1:

```
    Event   F1Score C3Score
0    A         4       3
1    B         2       4
2    C         3       5
3    D         4       4
4    E         5       5
...  ...      ...     ...
100  Z         2      5
```

And a second one, smaller like this:

df2

```
   Event   F1ScoreRequirement  F2ScoreRequirement
0    A            4                    3
1    D            4                    3
2    Z            4                    3
```

Effectively, I have a huge dataframe of all possible Events(Classes) and avg scores for each Group(cohort). And then a bunch of smaller data sets that contain the required score to pass for each Event(Class) for each Group(Cohort).

I want to add a column to my first dataframe, for each column that has the corresponding values from the smaller dataframes.

GoalFrame

```
    Event   F1Score F1ScoreRequirement F2Score F2ScoreRequirement  C3Score ... D2Score
0    A         4       4                  3           3              ...
1    B         2                          4                          ...
2    C         3                          5                          ...
3    D         4       4                  4           3              ...
4    E         5                          5                          ...
...  ...      ...     ...                ...         ...             ...
100  Z         2       5                  5           3              ...
```

I managed to do it manually, but the database is pretty large and the code run really slowly so I am looking for a Pandas-way or numpy to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use df.merge : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

In your code,

> final_df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on=['Event'])